Portable way to set PROJ_DATA path when installing proj/gdal with vcpkg
Edit:
It appears that my issue had to do with installing gdal (and later versions of PROJ) with vcpkg.  PROJ was looking in the wrong place for the PROJ_DATA dir where the required proj.db is located.  To resolve this, I needed to set the proj.db.  I did that using the following:
To my CMake, I added:
find_package(PROJ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_path(PROJ_DATA_DIR
    NAMES proj.db
    PATHS "${PROJ_DIR}"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    REQUIRED
)
add_compile_definitions(MY_PROJ_DIR="${PROJ_DATA_DIR}")

This obtained the path to share/proj, and defined a macro MY_PROJ_DIR with it.
I then added a helper function:
// hpp file
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace MYLIB {
    void setProjDataSearchPaths(std::vector<fs::path> customSearchPaths = {});
};

// cpp file
#include "MYLIB/set_proj_data.hpp"

#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "proj.h"

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace MYLIB {
    static bool PROJ_PATH_SET = false;

    void setProjDataSearchPaths(std::vector<fs::path> customSearchPaths)
    {
        if (!PROJ_PATH_SET) {
            std::cout << "Setting default PROJ_DATA paths to: \n";
            std::vector<const char*> cstrings(customSearchPaths.size() + 1);
            std::string defaultStr = MY_PROJ_DIR;
            cstrings[0] = defaultStr.c_str();

            for (size_t i = 1; i < customSearchPaths.size() + 1; ++i) {
                cstrings[i] = customSearchPaths[i - 1].string().c_str();
            }

            for (const char* searchPath : cstrings) {
                std::cout << "  " << searchPath << "\n";
            }

            proj_context_set_search_paths(NULL, customSearchPaths.size() + 1, cstrings.data());

            PROJ_PATH_SET = true;
        };
    };
};

I then call this function from within my library where it is required to correctly set the path.  In the event that a user wishes to manually add their own search paths, they can manually call setProjDataSearchPaths()` before calling routines from my API.
This works by calling the proj_context_set_search_paths with the default context (specified by passing in NULL).  This will cause all subsequent PROJ contexts to search the specified paths.
Original post:

I have many DEMs that are not of the Earth, but rather other celestial bodies.  They all have their own reference ellipsoid defined using semi-major and semi-minor axes.  For a given GeoTIFF I am using the GDAL C++ API to load the raster data in, and I would like to convert a given pixel to latitude and longitude using GDAL.
Here is how I load the projection data:
// Open the file:
GDALAllRegister();
CPLErr gdalError;
const GDALAccess eAccess = GA_ReadOnly;
GDALDatasetUniquePtr poDataset = GDALDatasetUniquePtr(GDALDataset::FromHandle(GDALOpen(filepath.string().c_str(), eAccess)));

// Read GeoTIFF projection data:
std::string projRef = poDataset->GetProjectionRef();
if (projRef.empty()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not read ProjectionRef from " + filepath.string());
}

// Read the GeoTransform (model tie-point and pixel scale):
double adfGeoTransform[6];
gdalError = poDataset->GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
if (gdalError != CE_None) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not read the GeoTransform from " + filepath.string());
}

This appears to work correctly, as projRef takes on the value of:
PROJCS["SIMPLE_CYLINDRICAL MOON",GEOGCS["GCS_MOON",DATUM["D_MOON",SPHEROID["MOON",1737400,0]],PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",180],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]

which looks like what I am expecting it to be.  Now, I want to transform a given pixel into a latitude and longitude coordinate.  Previously, I was using the proj API directly (which worked) but have switched to using the gdal API, so my assumption was I would create an OGRSpatialReference using: +proj=longlat +a=<SemiMajor> +b=<SemiMinor> (for example, using the corresponding values for the moon above, that'd be: +proj=longlat +a=1737400.000000 +b=1737400.000000)
My code for setting up the OGRCoordinateTransformation* is:
OGRSpatialReference srcSRS = OGRSpatialReference(projData.projRef.c_str());
double a = srcSRS.GetSemiMajor();
double b = srcSRS.GetSemiMinor();

std::string latlonProjStr = "+proj=longlat +a=";
latlonProjStr += std::to_string(a);
latlonProjStr += " +b=";
latlonProjStr += std::to_string(b);

OGRSpatialReference dstSRS;
OGRErr ogrErr = dstSRS.importFromProj4(latlonProjStr.c_str());
OGRCoordinateTransformation* poTransform = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&srcSRS, &dstSRS);

When I run this however, ogrErr is 5 (which, according to the docs is: OGRERR_CORRUPT_DATA ), poTransform is a nullptr, and the following errors are printed:
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name

(The importFromProj4() throws the first error, while the OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation() throws the second)
So it looks as though my proj string is invalid, however this is the exact same proj string I was using originally when I was still using the proj API directly, so I am unsure what exactly is not valid about it here.
Ultimately, I am just after a way of being able to construct the OGRCoordinateTransformation to convert an arbitrary pixel to geoedetic (lat/lon) coordiantes.  (I am familiar with needing to use adGeoTransform array for the affine transform, I am purely looking for how to configure the OGRCoordinateTransformation, which I believe requires setting up the OGRSpatialReference, I am just unsure how to correctly use the SemiMajor and SemiMinor axes to do this)

